# Получение скриншота структуры внутри TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf

Как получить скриншот всей структуры дерева TreeView?
Делал это следующим кодом, но он получает изображение только видимой области дерева:

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)TreeElement.ActualWidth, (int)TreeElement.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

renderTargetBitmap.Render(TreeElement);

JpegBitmapEncoder jpegBitmapEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder
{
    QualityLevel = 100
};
jpegBitmapEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));

using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("Tree.jpg", FileMode.Create))
{
    jpegBitmapEncoder.Save(fileStream);
    fileStream.Close();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема вот в чём.

Вы получаете правильный скриншот: ваш `TreeView` *именно так и выглядит*. У него внутри есть `ScrollViewer`, который и ограничивает видимость.

Есть несколько путей решения проблемы. Самый простой, вероятно — просмотреть дочерние элементы нашего `TreeView` и найти «внутреннюю часть» `ScrollViewer`'а.

Это делается так:

```
IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> GetChildren(FrameworkElement fe)
{
    int nChildren = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(fe);
    for (int i = 0; i < nChildren; i++)
        yield return (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(fe, i);
}

IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> GetAllChildren(FrameworkElement fe) =>
    new[] { fe }.Concat(GetChildren(fe).SelectMany(GetAllChildren));
```

Или, если вы работаете с новой .NET 4.7.1, то

```
IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> GetAllChildren(FrameworkElement fe) =>
    GetChildren(fe).SelectMany(GetAllChildren).Prepend(fe);
```

Подсмотрев в визуальное дерево при помощи Live Visual Tree, видим, что нам нужен дочерний элемент типа `ScrollContentPresenter`.

Пишем:

```
var presenter = GetAllChildren(TreeElement).OfType<ScrollContentPresenter>().First();
var content = (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(presenter, 0);
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap =
    new RenderTargetBitmap((int)content .ActualWidth,
                           (int)content .ActualHeight,
                           96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

renderTargetBitmap.Render(content);

JpegBitmapEncoder jpegBitmapEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder { QualityLevel = 100 };
jpegBitmapEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));

using (var fileStream = File.Create("Tree.jpg"))
    jpegBitmapEncoder.Save(fileStream);
```

Недостаток: вы не получаете цвет фона, т. к. фон рисуется выше по визуальному дереву. Но «подложить» фон на картинку вы уж сможете сами, хорошо?